# How to count occurrences of a value for a specific attribute

Tags: powerbi

I would like to get a count for attributes based on the values (grouped by attribute) and how often it appears, except 0.

As I don't really know how to explain it best, this is the dataset I have:

[image]

How I would a result table to be presented is:

| Attribute | Count of |
| --- | --- |
| Q5_1 | 0 |
| Q5_2 | 3 |
| Q5_3 | 1 |
| Q5_4 | 1 |
| Q5_5 | 0 |
| Q5_6 | 0 |
| Q5_7 | 0 |

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution - but I can't test it unless you provide a sample file or something I can copy/paste.

This is a table expression to count `Values` per `Attribute` except `Values` equal zero.

```
NewTable =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Table[Attribute]
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Table),
        Table[Values] <> 0
    )
)
```